# Getting data from current date and same date last year

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, compare, period

I spent some hours searching and coding but i am not able to find a solution.
I have a table with dates (format yyyy-mm-dd) and payment value.
Each row after agregating has only one date e related values.
I need generate a resultset with the folowing format:
[date] [value from current date] [value from date exact last year] [value from same day from last month]

Anyone could help me?
My DB is BigQuery.

> `--Didn't work
> select
> current.date,
> previous.date
> --extract(year from previous.date) -1
>
> from
> `f_table.agg` current
> left join `f_table.agg` previous
> on extract(day from current.date) = extract(day from previous.date)
> and (extract(month from current.date) = extract(month from previous.date)
> and extract(year from current.date) = (extract(year from previous.date) - 1) )`

> --Didn't work
> select
> current.date,
> sum(current.value)
> --lag( sum(current.value), 1) over (order by extract(year from current.date))
>
> from
> `f_table.agg` current
>
> group by current.date
> order by current.date desc

Answer (score 0):

> I need generate a resultset with the folowing format: `date` `value from current date` `value from date exact last year` `value from same day from last month`

I think you can try `self join` like below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH `f_table.agg` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-04-15' date, 10 value UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-04-29', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-15', 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-04-15', 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-04-27', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-04-28', 60 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-04-29', 70
)
-- query starts here
SELECT cur.date, cur.value,
       last_year.value AS last_year_value,
       last_month.value AS last_month_value
  FROM `f_table.agg` cur
  LEFT JOIN `f_table.agg` last_year ON cur.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR = last_year.date
  LEFT JOIN `f_table.agg` last_month ON cur.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH = last_month.date;
```

**Query result**

[image]

Comment: YES! It is it. Sorry for my super late reply, but worked. Thank you very much!